# Create a new navigation term in SPO TermStore from Azure Function (PnP PowerShell)

Tags: pnp-powershell, azure-ad, azure-functions

I'm trying to automate the creation of a TermStore term and apply a simple navigation link. I finally got my Azure Function to connect to SPO and query data, but when I use the New-PnPTerm command below, I get an access denied error.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -ClientId $appId -Thumbprint $thumbPrint –Url https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com -Tenant <tenant>.onmicrosoft.com
New-PnPTerm -TermSet <termset> -TermGroup "Navigation" -Name $item.FieldValues.Title -LocalCustomProperties @{"_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl"="$($item.FieldValues.SharePointURL)"}
```

> [Error] ERROR: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform
> this action or access this resource

My Azure Function uses a certificate to authenticate via the Azure AD app registration, which has the following API permissions:

- Graph.Group.ReadWrite.All
- Graph.TermStore.ReadWrite.All
- Graph.User.ReadWrite.All
- SharePoint.AllSites.FullControl
- SharePoint.Sites.FullControl.All
- SharePoint.TermStore.ReadWrite.All
- SharePoint.User.ReadWrite.All

Even better would be if this can be done in a Logic App. I wasn't able to find a connector or REST endpoint that would support this. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Azure App Registration and Term Store: Solution for Access Denied

Navigate to the term store admin center, and add app@sharepoint as a term store admin.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Denis. That took care of my auth issue.